# Yum autoremove removing packages that are standalone

Tags: fedora, package-management, yum

If I run `sudo yum autoremove` it outputs what it is going to remove for confirmation. However, some of these packages it is removing are things I want but are not dependencies of anything else...

What causes this and can it be prevented?

Comment: Some good suggestions on [unix.stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23330/how-can-i-remove-orphan-packages-in-fedora)

Comment: Does the output of `yumdb search reason user` show the packages you want to remove?

Comment: @davidbaumann Yes, it does. Anything that I install through yum that had no dependencies and isn't a dependency of something else show up, along with others

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want packages to be deleted, as they were installed as dependency before, you must mark them as installed:

```
yum install #package
```

Now it will say somethink like "already installed, marked as manually installed".

Comment: But I manually installed things like youtube-dl and ack. It still wants to remove them

Comment: Please post the output of `yum install youtube-dl` and `yum autoremove`.

Comment: I did it with `lshw` because I had already installed youtube-dl. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0f144e6ae19f61f4e897

Comment: Where is the output of "yum autoremove"? Can you mark something as solution?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `yumdb set reason user PACKAGE`

If `yumdb` command is not found then first do `yum install yum-utils`