# Yum / dnf tries to remove standalone packages as dependencies

Tags: centos, fedora, yum, package-management, packages

When I try to `yum remove texlive` it lists all the packages it will remove as dependencies 'only to `texlive`', but for example `gcc` is listed. But I want to leave it in the system. Can I somehow specify packages to leave? I tried the hint from [Yum autoremove removing packages that are standalone](https://superuser.com/questions/855302/yum-autoremove-removing-packages-that-are-standalone) of `yum install gcc` to 'fix it as user-installed', but this works only when the package is installed as standalone BEFORE it is installed as a dependency.

Does anyone has a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a `dnf`-managed system, run `dnf mark install gcc` as root to mark `gcc` as user-installed.  Run `dnf mark remove gcc` as root to mark `gcc` as installed merely to satisfy other packages’ dependencies.

On a `yum`-managed system, run `yumdb set reason user gcc` as root to mark `gcc` as user-installed.  Run `yumdb set reason dep gcc` as root to mark `gcc` as installed merely to satisfy other packages’ dependencies.

(Giving credit where credit is due, I learned the `yum` answer from [David Haller’s answer](https://serverfault.com/a/563976) to an equivalent question on Server Fault and a [blog post](https://blog.christophersmart.com/2013/06/12/how-to-list-packages-you-have-explicitly-installed-using-yum/) by Christopher Smart, both of which led me to the `yumdb` man page discussion of the `reason` key.  For `dnf`, [Havner’s comment](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1125925#c9) in a RedHat Bugzilla bug report led me to the `dnf` man page discussion of `dnf mark`.)

Comment: On amazonlinux 2 I get `bash: yumdb: command not found` so had to do the (non-obvious) `yum install yum-utils` first